# How to insert a bell character \007 using sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

How to insert a bell character \007 using sublime into a text file. I must be missing it.

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make use of the Python API:

- open the ST3 Python console (View menu -> Show Console)
- type `view.run_command('insert', { 'characters': '\007' })` <kbd>Enter</kbd>